# Changing Image In a Button After Being Clicked?

Tags: xml, android, button

Creating a game in Android using multiple Buttons to display an image from the drawable folder. I want to change the button to a different image after the button has been clicked on. Here is the button code:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/b36"
    android:background="@drawable/black"
    android:layout_width="45px"
    android:layout_height="45px"
    />
```

I can't find anything about how to change the actual image of the button. You can change the color of the button by using the following code in the java file:

```
b36.setBackgroundColor(0xAA00AA00);
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use image view as button. set the image view's background to a xml file. in resource drawable we can use xml files. check the Api demos drawable folder. that xml file contains this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button _image_in_normal_state" />

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button _image_in_pressed_state" />

</selector>
```

and put those to image files in res/drawable folder. you can achieve what you want?

also refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/package-summary.html)

Comment: This helped me out a lot, but as it turns out you can use this for most views including Button as it is. you just set the image background to this resource file. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).  Then you can call methods like `button.setImageDrawable()` and such.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example for changing the background of a button once pressed.

In the oncreate of your activity:

```
   btn_36= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b36);
   btn_36.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           btn_36.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white);
       }
   });
```